# AngularJS and ng-pdfviewer no render pdf file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to render a pdf file (using [ng-pdfviewer](https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer)) in my AngularJS app, but I have many problems...
The most important is that when i run the app in my local environment everything works fine, the pdf is rendered properly, but when i run "grunt build" (as I run in the "prod" server), the same pdf is not rendered.

Here's my grunt localbuild task:

```
grunt.registerTask('localbuild', [
    'clean:dist',
    'ngconstant:development',
    'wiredep',
    'sass',
    'mergejson',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin',
    'karma'
 ]);
```

Furthermore, in my local environment, I can see many "console.logs()" corresponding to the process to load and render the file. When I compile the app, I can just see the load pdf "console.log", the one which corresponds to the render process have been missed.

Comment: Could you show the build script?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell thanks or your interest, i just updated the question with the grunt task.

Comment: Are there any custom scripts or are those all default ones?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell all are the default ones

Comment: Sadly, I can't say what's causing your issue. My only suggestion is to go through every task regarding anything JS related and check when and where your logs are being removed

Comment: @ChrisSatchell thanks for your time! As soon as I find any solution I'm goint to post it right there.